# Magento 2 upgrade to latest version

Tags: magento, magento2

I want to upgrade my Magento 2 Store from Magento 2.2.9 to Magento 2.4.2.

1.) Can I upgrade it directly to Magento 2.4.2 ?

2.) Can I upgrade it first to 2.3 version then upgrade to 2.4 version?

Please give your valuable suggestions.

Comment: hope this will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319193/upgrade-magento-2-3-3-to-2-4

Comment: @Kashif Please check my question. My question is if I can upgrade Magento 2.2 directly to 2.4 or need to upgrade to 2.3 first and then 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

You can't upgrade directly from 2.2.9 to 2.4 because Magento 2.4.x requires PHP 7.4 and Elasticsearch. My suggestion is to upgrade to 2.3.0 and change PHP version to 7.2 then upgrade to 2.3.3. You have to change PHP version to 7.3 and then upgrade to 2.3.6. Last step, change PHP version to 7.4 and install Elasticsearch then upgrade to 2.4.2. Backup files and database before starting upgrade.